# How to make Typewriter overwrite existing file

Tags: typewriter

Sometimes Typewriter generates `output (1).ts` files. How can I make it to overwrite the existing files?

Comment: I have to open VS as an admin to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Typewriter keeps track of which source file was used to generate the output file in order to automatically update the output file whenever the source file changes. Sometimes this tracking gets out of sync resulting in this behaviour.

To resolve the issue you'll need to delete both `output.ts` and `output (1).ts` and then render the `.tst` template or save the `c#` source file.